# scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.pdf() vs.scipy.stats.normal.pdf()

Tags: python, gaussian, jax, scipy.stats

I am probably missing something, but I'm struggling to understand how `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.pdf()` and `scipy.stats.norm.pdf()` are different.

```
import jax.scipy.stats as stats
from jax import random

key = random.PRNGKey(0)
x = random.normal(key, (5,))
multivariate = stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(x, 0, 1)
univariate= stats.norm.pdf(x, 0, 1)

print(f"Input: {x}")
'Input: [ 0.18784384 -1.2833426  -0.2710917   1.2490594   0.24447003]'

print(f"Multivariate: {multivariate}")
'Multivariate: [0.3919656  0.1750957  0.38454908 0.18286388 0.38719714]'

print(f"Univariate : {univariate}")
'Univariate : [0.3919656  0.1750957  0.38454908 0.18286388 0.38719714]'
```

How would you then get a normalized density for a multivariate normal using scipy? I.e. get a scalar density for a vector input?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of computing the multivariate normal density for five points in two dimensions with a given mean and covariance:

```py
import jax.scipy.stats as stats
from jax import random
import jax.numpy as jnp

key = random.PRNGKey(0)
x = random.normal(key, (5, 2))  # 5 points in 2 dimensions

mean = jnp.array([1., 2.])  # 2D mean
cov = jnp.array([[1., 0.5], [0.5, 2.]])  # 2D covariance

multivariate = stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean, cov)
print(multivariate)
# [0.03425725 0.01604864 0.0237349  0.01234392 0.07168635]
```

Answer (score 0):

After following @jakevdp's answer, it appears as though the mean argument's shape to `.multivariate_normal` methods determines the shape of the output, and consequently, if we treat an N-dim input as N independent realizations of a univariate normal, or an N-dim realization of an N-dim multivariate normal. However, it is important to also be aware of the covariance argument's shape:

```
import jax.scipy.stats as stats
from jax import random
import jax.numpy as jnp

key = random.PRNGKey(0)
x = random.normal(key, (3,))  # 5 points in 2 dimensions

# Univariate
univariate = stats.norm.pdf(x, 0, 1)

# Multivariate with scalar mean and covariance
scalar_mean = 1
scalar_cov = 1
print(stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(x, scalar_mean, scalar_cov))
# [0.2859504  0.13291785 0.32084033]


# Multivariate with vector mean and matrix covariance
mean = jnp.array([1., 1., 1.,])  # vector mean
cov = jnp.eye(3)  # matrix covariance
print(stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean, cov))
# 0.012194471

# Multivariate with vector mean and scalar covariance 
mean = jnp.array([1., 1., 1.,])  # vector mean
cov = 1  # scalar covariance
print(stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean, cov))
# 0.012194471

# Multivariate with vector mean and vector covariance
mean = jnp.array([1., 1., 1.,])  # vector mean
cov = jnp.array([1., 1., 1.,])  # vector covariance
print(stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean, cov)) 
# 'Raises ValueError: multivariate_normal.logpdf got incompatible 
# shapes'

# Multivariate with vector mean and diagonal covariance matrix 
mean = jnp.array([1., 1., 1.,])  # vector mean
cov = jnp.diag(jnp.array([1., 3., 5.,]))  # matrix covariance
print(stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean, cov))
# 0.007798877
```